# How do I force a plain text copy in CKEditor5 (ie, only allow cmd/ctrl + shift + v and disallow cmd/ctrl + v)?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

How do I force a plain text copy in CKEditor5 (ie, only allow cmd/ctrl + shift + v and disallow cmd/ctrl + v)?

I'm using React in Next.js.

We've tried some code we found on Stack Overflow but it's not in React friendly format and hard to decipher or convert to React.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.